# Does get_template_part pull data once in a loop?

Tags: loop, get-template-part

When i use the **"get_template_part();" inside a loop**, does it search for that template file **every cycle** of the loop (each post) **or** does it search for the file **once** and then reuse it every cycle of the loop?

Comment: Are you asking if php has to load from disk every cycle of your loop? I'd expect not. Many themes include parts within their loops. I've never found a performance hit from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_template_part()` calls `locate_template()`, and both functions are running `file_exists()` checks for the same file over and over. There is no caching. Meh.

But … PHP has an internal cache for file look-ups, so a direct file access will not happen on every call.

There is an edge case, most developers aren't aware of: A file can be deleted after the first access, and `file_exists()` will still return `true` if PHP's cache hasn't updated.

Comment: So if i except a large number of loops on one page should i just insert the code?

Comment: Or call `locate_template()` once and save the value for reuse.

Answer (score 2):

That depends entirely on your code.  Without seeing any, i will assume you are using a standard WP loop.  If so, the template part is included every time the statement is executed.  By default that is for every post in the loop.